# Cython: check if symbol is defined in extern header

Tags: python, c, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to write some Cython code that'll work on multiple *nix systems. I have a pxd files where I essentially do this:

```
cdef extern from 'lib.h' nogil:
    cdef enum option_enum:
        LIB_O_OPTION_1
        LIB_O_OPTION_2
        ...
        LIB_O_OPTION_N

    cdef void lib_function(int options)
```

On some systems some options aren't defined. This leads to an undefined symbol error at compile time, as the C code Cython generates uses the enum values.

In C code this could be circumvented using a macro to check information about the system, and then only use options that are available. Seeing as there's no macro support, what's the best way to handle this issue with Cython?

Comment: your are probably looking for conditional statements: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#conditional-statements

Comment: Using IF/DEF from your link I was able to solve my problem, but that still doesn't provide a mechanism to check if a value is defined. In my case I know the value won't be defined if `int(UNAME_RELEASE[0]) < 4`, but in general the question remains unanswered. Thanks for the link in any case; it's very useful.